# Proxy requests in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-proxy, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following code.

```
#example.py

import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def foo():
    conn = aiohttp.ProxyConnector(proxy='http://222.222.251.185:9797')
    r = await aiohttp.get('https://www.python.org/', connector=conn)
    return await r.read()

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(500):
    tasks.append(foo())
    for r in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        print(await r)

parsed_data = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

When I do not use proxy, everything is OK. But when I use proxy, program is crashing with that trace:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vika/Work/example.py", line 19, in <module>
    parsed_data = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 337, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/vika/Work/example.py", line 16, in main
    print(await r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 486, in _wait_for_one
    return f.result()  # May raise f.exception().
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/home/vika/Work/example.py", line 7, in foo
    r = await aiohttp.get('https://www.python.org/', connector=conn)
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 552, in __await__
    return (yield from self._coro)
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 174, in _request
    conn = yield from self._connector.connect(req)
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 307, in connect
    transport, proto = yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 683, in _create_connection
    resp = yield from proxy_resp.start(conn, True)
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 597, in start
    message = yield from httpstream.read()
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 578, in read
    result = yield from super().read()
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 433, in read
    yield from self._waiter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 358, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 290, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object foo at 0x7fcf51566518>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vika/Work/example.py", line 7, in foo
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 552, in __await__
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 174, in _request
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 307, in connect
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 686, in _create_connection
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 84, in close
  File "/opt/python_custom/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 375, in _release
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 569, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 447, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 456, in _call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 284, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <coroutine object foo at 0x7fcf515664c0>
...
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<foo() done, defined at /home/vika/Work/example.py:5> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[as_completed.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py:472]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<foo() done, defined at /home/vika/Work/example.py:5> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[as_completed.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py:472]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<foo() done, defined at /home/vika/Work/example.py:5> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[as_completed.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py:472]>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<foo() done, defined at /home/vika/Work/example.py:5> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]> cb=[as_completed.<locals>._on_completion() at /usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py:472]>
```

What could be the problem? 
I used different proxies, so th problem must be in code logic.

Comment: You have an `aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError` exactly when connecting to the proxy. Are you sure you have working proxies? Try setting the proxy in your browser first to see if it is reliable

Comment: @JBernardo You are right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy was wrong. Different proxies cause different errors, so it was hard to find one fine proxy. The code above is absolutely valid (but pls change the proxy!).